# can I clear buttons from the previous screen before changing states?

Tags: c#, xna

I am building a game in C# with Xna. When I change game states between the menu and the play screen it's as if the new screen is just drawn over the new screen. When I click the part of the screen where the buttons were on the previous screen, it changes state, if I'm on level one and hit the part of the screen where the level 2 button is on the previous screen it jumps straight to level 2.

This is my code from the first menu button class :

```
 class menubutton1
{
    public bool selected = false;
    public string text = "menuButton";

    public Rectangle area;

    public menubutton1(Rectangle Area, string Text, int i) 
    { 
        area = Area; 
        text = Text;
        i = 4;
    }

    public void mouseOver(MouseState mbd)
    {
        //CHECK IF MOUSE IS OVER BUTTON
        if (mbd.X > area.X && mbd.X < area.X + area.Width && mbd.Y > area.Y && mbd.Y > area.Y + area.Height)
        {
            selected = true;
        }
        else { selected = false; }
    }



    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, SpriteFont font)
    {
        if (selected == false) 
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text, new Vector2(area.X, area.Y), Color.Black);
        }
        if (selected == true) 
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text, new Vector2(area.X, area.Y), Color.White);
        }
    }

}
}
```

and this is the code from the main:

```
 List<menubutton1> mbs1 = new List<menubutton1>();
```

This is from the update method:

```
 foreach (menubutton1 m in mbs1)
        {
            m.mouseOver(mbd);
            //Check if play button has been clicked
                if (m.text == "PLAY GAME 1" && m.selected == true && mbd.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevmbd.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                {
                    gamestate = gameState.play1;
                }
                if (m.text == "PLAY GAME 2" && m.selected == true && mbd.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevmbd.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                {
                    gamestate = gameState.play2;
                }
                if (m.text == "PLAY GAME 3" && m.selected == true && mbd.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prevmbd.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                {
                     gamestate = gameState.play3;
                }



        }
```

Is there anyway to stop this from happening? Is there a way to clear the buttons from the previous screen, before changing states to move to the new screen?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This strongly depends on how you setup your UI and the interaction. If you use events, to capture button-taps, clear those when changing the Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want to set it up.
One way to do it would be to use GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black); Which will leave you a black screen that you can draw on. Another way would be to make multiple classes and when it changes GameStates make it load a Draw from a specific class, which will only draw what is in that one class.